# Web-safe fonts: do Apple devices ship with Arial?

Tags: font, windows-os, mac-os-x, apple

Currently my font stack is `"HelveticaNeue-Light","Helvetica Neue Light","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,"Lucida Grande",sans-serif`. The issue I'm having is that some of my images/buttons with text are forced to be either HelveticaNeue or Arial - one or the other, obviously. If a user without Helvetica (Windows users) visits, the Arial body text clashes with the HelveticaNeue button text, and then vice versa.

If I use Arial as the first font in the font-stack, will a large portion of Apple users see Arial? **Does Arial ship with Apple devices, and if so, when did they start this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like Arial has been shipping with Macs at least since OS 10.0 was released:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typefaces_included_with_Mac_OS_X

So it looks like all Mac users will see Arial.

for all iOS fonts, a site previously mentioned on SE: iosfonts.com

Comment: I guess by "devices", he means iOS...

Comment: ah, well not sure for all iOS releases but the latest has Arial: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4980?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Comment: I meant both iOS and OS X - computers are technically devices :) Thanks for the links!

Comment: for all iOS fonts, a site previously mentioned on SE: http://iosfonts.com